# Sencha Touch: How to build a restful proxy url syntax?

Tags: rest, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Defined as a model and its associations, I wish the http calls to follow best practices of restful. For example, if I make the call

```
user.posts();
```

I wish to run a call http defined as

```
users/1/posts
```

If a call is then put on post with id 32 then the url of reference must be

```
users/1/posts/32
```

So I want to avoid using the filter property as is the default for a get

```
/posts.php?filter=[{"property":"user_id","value":1}]
```

This is because the api rest are already defined and I can not change them.
I would like to build a minimally invasive solution and reading on various forums the best way is to **do an ovveride the method buildURL the proxy rest** but was not able to retrieve all the data needed to build the final URL. Can anyone give me an example?

thanks

Comment: The standard Sencha REST proxy (http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest) handles this for you, but it sounds more like you are looking specifically for custom *association* proxy functionality.

Also - when you say "was not able to retrieve all the data needed to build the final URL" - can you please elaborate? What are you not able to retrieve that is preventing you from building the override?

Comment: I use proxy rest but as I said the default does not use the rest standard when it is necessary to refer to nested resources. For example if I want to see all tasks associated at one user, according to the standard rest should do a call get:

"http://domain.com/user/1/tasks" 

Instead REST PROXY makes a call on
"http://domain.com/tasks.php?filter=[{"property":"user_id","value":1}]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
window.serverUrl = "192.168.1.XX"
var service = "login.php"

var dataTosend: {
    username:"xx",
     password: "yy"
}
var methode:"POST" / "GET"
this.service(service,methode,dataTosend,onSucessFunction,onFailureFunction);

onSucessFunction: function(res) {
   alert("onSucessFunction"):
},

onFailureFunction: function(res) {
   alert("onFailureFunction"):
},


service: function(svc, callingMethod, data, successFunc, failureFunc) {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            scope: this,
            useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
            method: callingMethod,
            url: window.serverUrl + svc,
            params: data,
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            },
            failure: failureFunc,
            success: successFunc
        });
```

I hope this will solve your problem...